# Selector forms, on submit how to send WordPress query variables to URL using jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a series of selector fields in a form. (The values of each selector are passed in to variables.) Once all fields are selected the submit button sends the user to the page with products sorted by a single category and multiple product characteristics using the www.mydomain.com/?product_cat=cat-name&characteristics=foo,bar,candy URL query.

The query works when I type it into the browser. When I try passing it through using jQuery it only passes the question mark (www.mydomain.com/?). If I remove the question mark then the rest of the string passes through. Am I using the wrong method? Here's my code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("#msform").submit(function() {
    var homeType = $("#homeType").val(); //drop down selector value builds 1st part of category name
    var eqType = $("#eqType").val(); // drop down selector value builds last part of category name
    var sqType = $("#sqType").val(); // product characteristic value from drop down selector
    var flowType = $("#flowType").val();  // prod char value
    var locationType = $("#locationType").val(); //prod char value
    var urlSet =  "/?product_cat="+homeType+"-"+eqType+"&characteristics="+sqType+","+flowType+","+locationType; // URL I wish to send the visitor to after clicking submit button


$("#msform").attr('action', urlSet);

    $("#msform").submit();
    });
});
```

I have tried using ascii codes for the question mark. I have escaped the question mark but nothing seems to allow the whole string to pass to the URL.

Comment: try like $("#msform").attr('action', home_url()+urlSet);

Comment: it seems you are submitting form 2 times

Comment: I commented out the second submit and added the home_url()+ but I get the same results. www.mydomain.com/?

Comment: you are appending attr after submitting, try append before submit

Answer (score 0):

below code is just a try, Its better to do ajax form submission

```
jQuery(function($) {
  homeType = $("#homeType").val();
  eqType = $("#eqType").val();
  sqType = $("#sqType").val();
  flowType = $("#flowType").val();
  locationType = $("#locationType").val();

  urlSet =  "<?php echo home_url();?>/?product_cat="+homeType+"-"+eqType+"&characteristics="+sqType+","+flowType+","+locationType;
  $("#msform").attr('action', urlSet);
  $("#msform").submit(function() {console.log('submit success')});

});
```

Comment: This also breaks. The output for this code is www.mydomain.com/<. My original code works if you remove the question mark "?" but I need the question mark in order for WordPress to run the product query. In your example it breaks before the question mark, in mine it breaks after the question mark.